# Como destravar os accordions mesmo quando da alguma excepetion

Tags: c#, jquery

Tenho uma tela que libera os `accordions` assim que é validado o codígo do cliente com as informações pessoais, etc.
Porém se ocorre alguma `exception` ele trava os `accordions`, como poderia fazer para deixar liberado mesmo que desse algum tipo de `exception` ?

Tela normal com os `accordions` liberados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que dá alguma `exception` no `code behind` / `classe` os `accordions` somem ou travam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função que libera os `accordions` que vão setar os dados aos campos:

```
function ConsultarCliente() {
for (var i = 1; i <= totalpanels; i++) { //Expande os accordions
    $('#cp-' + i).find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px -' + 20 + 'px');
    $('#cp-' + i).find('.expandable-panel-content').css('margin-top', 0);
}
var codCli = $("[id$=txtCodigo]").val();
if (codCli != "") {
    var data = ConsultarClienteAjax(codCli);
    if (data.CliCodigo != "" && data.CliCodigo != null) {

        for (var i = 1; i <= totalpanels; i++) {
            $('#cp-' + i).find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px -' + 20 + 'px');
            $('#cp-' + i).find('.expandable-panel-content').css('margin-top', 0);
        }
        $("[id$=txtCodigo]").val(codCli);
        $("[id$=txtSetor]").val(data.CliSetor);
        $("[id$=txtAgencia]").val($.trim(data.CliAgencia));
        $("[id$=txtBairro]").val($.trim(data.CliBairro));
        $("[id$=txtBairroEntrega]").val($.trim(data.CliBairro2));
        $("[id$=txtCodBanco]").val($.trim(data.CliBanco));
        retornarNomeBanco();
        if (data.CliCiclo != "" && data.CliCiclo != null) {
            $("[id$=txtCiclo]").val(data.CliCiclo.substring(4, 6) + "/" + data.CliCiclo.substring(0, 4));
        }
        if (data.CliCicloDig != "" && data.CliCicloDig != null) {
            $("[id$=txtCicloDig]").val(data.CliCicloDig.substring(4, 6) + "/" + data.CliCicloDig.substring(0, 4));

        }
        if (data.CliTpBonus == "S") {
            $("[id$=rblBonus]").val("B");
            $("[id$=txtBrinde1]").val($.trim(data.CLIBRINDE));
            // $("[id$=txtBrinde1]").blur();
        } else {
            $("[id$=rblBonus]").val("D");
        }
        $("[id$=txtCep]").val($.trim(data.CliCep.substring(0, 5) + "-" + data.CliCep.substring(5, 8)));
        if ($.trim(data.CliCep2).length > 0) { $("[id$=txtCepEntrega]").val($.trim(data.CliCep2.substring(0, 5) + "-" + data.CliCep2.substring(5, 8))); }
        $("[id$=txtCidade]").val($.trim(data.CliCidade));
        $("[id$=txtCidadeEntrega]").val($.trim(data.CliCidade2));
        $("[id$=txtConta]").val($.trim(data.CliConta));
        if ($.trim(data.CliCPFCGC).length == 11) {
            $("[id$=txtCpfCnpj]").val(data.CliCPFCGC.substring(0, 3) + "." + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(3, 6) + "." + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(6, 9) + "-" + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(9, 11));
        } else if ($.trim(data.CliCPFCGC).length == 14) {
            $("[id$=txtCpfCnpj]").val(data.CliCPFCGC.substring(0, 2) + "." + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(2, 5) + "." + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(5, 8) + "/" + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(8, 12) + "-" + data.CliCPFCGC.substring(12, 14));
        }
        $("[id$=txtDivisao]").val(data.CliDivisao);
        $("[id$=txtDtCad]").val($.trim(data.CliDtCad.substring(0, 10)));

        if (data.CliDtNasc != null) {
            $("[id$=txtDtNasc]").val($.trim(data.CliDtNasc.substring(0, 10)));
        }
        else {
            $("[id$=txtDtNasc]").val();
        }

        $("[id$=txtEmail]").val($.trim(data.CliEmail));
        $("[id$=txtEndereco]").val($.trim(data.CliEndereco));
        $("[id$=txtEnderecoEntrega]").val($.trim(data.CliEndereco2));
        $("[id$=txtIndicante]").val(data.CliCoordena);
        $("[id$=txtKitIni]").val($.trim(data.CliKitInicial));
        if (data.CliKitInicial != null && data.CliKitInicial.trim() != "") {
            var prod = ConsultarProdutoAjax($("[id$=txtKitIni]").val());
            if (prod.ProdCodigo != "" && prod.ProdCodigo != null) {
                $('[id$=txtKitDesr]').val(prod.ProdDescr);
                var setor = ConsultarSetorAjax(data.CliSetor);
                var formaPgto = ConsultarFormaPagtoAjax(setor.SetEmpresa, data.CliFPKitInicial);
                $("[id$=ddlFPgto]").append($("<option></option>").val(formaPgto.FPCodigo).html(formaPgto.FPCodigo + " - " + formaPgto.FPDescricao));
            }
        }
        $("[id$=txtNacionalidade]").val($.trim(data.CliNacionalidade));
        $("[id$=txtNome]").val($.trim(data.CliNome));
        $("[id$=txtObservacoes]").val($.trim(data.CliObs));
        if ($.trim(data.CliPis).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtPis]").val($.trim(data.CliPis).substring(0, 3) + "." + $.trim(data.CliPis).substring(3, 8) + "." + $.trim(data.CliPis).substring(8, 10) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliPis).substring(10, 11));
        }
        $("[id$=txtPontoReferencia]").val($.trim(data.CliPtoRef));
        $("[id$=txtPtoReferEntrega]").val($.trim(data.CliPtoRef2));
        $("[id$=txtRegiao]").val($.trim(data.CliRegiao));
        $("[id$=txtRgIe]").val($.trim(data.CliRGIE));
        $("[id$=txtRota]").val($.trim(data.CliRota));
        var regRota = ConsultarRegiaoRotaAjax(data.CliRegiao, data.CliRota);
        if (regRota.RegNome != null && regRota.RegNome != undefined) {
            $("[id$=txtRegiaoDescr]").val(regRota.RegNome);
            $("[id$=txtRotaDescr]").val(regRota.RegRotaNome);
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliTelCel).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtTelCel]").val("(" + $.trim(data.CliTelCel).substring(0, 2) + ")" + $.trim(data.CliTelCel).substring(2, 6) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliTelCel).substring(6, 11));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtTelCel]").val("");
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliTelCom).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtTelCom]").val("(" + $.trim(data.CliTelCom).substring(0, 2) + ")" + $.trim(data.CliTelCom).substring(2, 6) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliTelCom).substring(6, 11));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtTelCom]").val("");
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliTelRefCom).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtTelComer]").val("(" + $.trim(data.CliTelRefCom).substring(0, 2) + ")" + $.trim(data.CliTelRefCom).substring(2, 6) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliTelRefCom).substring(6, 11));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtTelComer]").val("");
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliTelRef).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtTelRefPess]").val("(" + $.trim(data.CliTelRef).substring(0, 2) + ")" + $.trim(data.CliTelRef).substring(2, 6) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliTelRef).substring(6, 11));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtTelRefPess]").val("");
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliTelRes).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=txtTelRes]").val("(" + $.trim(data.CliTelRes).substring(0, 2) + ")" + $.trim(data.CliTelRes).substring(2, 6) + "-" + $.trim(data.CliTelRes).substring(6, 11));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtTelRes]").val("");
        }
        $("[id$=txtTitular]").val($.trim(data.CliTitularBanco));
        $("[id$=txtNvlLotus]").val($.trim(data.CliNvlLotus));
        if ($.trim(data.CliCicloNomeacao).length == 6) {
            $("[id$=txtCicloNomeacao]").val(data.CliCicloNomeacao.substring(4, 6) + "/" + data.CliCicloNomeacao.substring(0, 4));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtCicloNomeacao]").val("");
        }
        if ($.trim(data.CliCicloVal).length == 6) {
            $("[id$=txtCicloVal]").val(data.CliCicloVal.substring(4, 6) + "/" + data.CliCicloVal.substring(0, 4));
        } else {
            $("[id$=txtCicloVal]").val("");
        }

        $("[id$=txtValPedidos]").val(data.CliValPedidos);
        $("[id$=txtQtdePedidos]").val(data.CliQtdePedidos);
        $("[id$=txtPremiacao]").val(data.CliPremiacao);
        $("[id$=txtPremiacaoDescr]").val(data.CliPremiacaoDescr);
        $("[id$=txtCred]").val(String(parseFloat(data.CliLimiteCred).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));
        $("[id$=txtConjuge]").val($.trim(data.CliConjuge));
        if (data.CliNomeInd != null) {
            $("[id$=txtNomeRef]").val(data.CliNomeInd);
        }
        else {
            $("[id$=txtIndicante]").blur();
        }

        $("[id$=txtNomeRefPess]").val($.trim(data.CliNomeRef));
        $("[id$=txtNoSPC]").val($.trim(data.CliNumConSPC));
        $("[id$=txtNivelLotus]").val(data.CliNivelLotus);
        $("[id$=txtGrauPar]").val($.trim(data.CliParentesco));
        $("[id$=txtEmpVD]").val($.trim(data.CliOutrasEVD));
        $("[id$=txtRefComer]").val($.trim(data.CliNomeRefCom));
        $('[id$=hfSelectedValue]').val(data.CliFPKitInicial);
        if ($.trim(data.CliEstCivil).length > 1) {
            $("[id$=ddlEstCivil]").val(data.CliEstCivil.substring(0, 1));
        }
        $("[id$=ddlEstCivil]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlGrauInst]").val(data.CliGrauInstrucao);
        $("[id$=ddlGrauInst]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlRenda]").val(data.CliRenda);
        $("[id$=ddlRenda]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlSexo]").val(data.CliSexo);
        $("[id$=ddlSexo]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlStatus]").val(data.CliStatus);
        $("[id$=ddlStatus]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlTempVen]").val(data.CliTempVen);
        $("[id$=ddlTempVen]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlTempVenD]").val(data.CliTempVD);
        $("[id$=ddlTempVenD]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlTipoReg]").val(data.CliTipoReg);
        $("[id$=ddlTipoReg]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlTpConta]").val(data.ClitpConta);
        $("[id$=ddlTpConta]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlUf]").val(data.CliUF);
        $("[id$=ddlUf]").change();
        $("[id$=ddlUFEntrega]").val(data.CliUF2);
        $("[id$=ddlUFEntrega]").change();
        if (data.CliDivConsum == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkDivContato]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkDivContato]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliImovel == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkImvProprio]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkImvProprio]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliMalaDir == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkMld]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkMld]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliPagaAnt == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkPgAnte]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkPgAnte]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliRecNovidades == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkRecNovidade]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkRecNovidade]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliEnviarSPC == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkSPC]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkSPC]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliMalaDir == 1) {
            $("[id$=chkMld]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkMld]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (data.CliCtrlEmpRec == "S") {
            $("[id$=chkContrato]").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("[id$=chkContrato]").prop("checked", false);
        }
        $("[id$=txtSetor]").blur();
        $("[id$=txtKitIni]").prop('disabled', true);
        $("[id$=txtKitDesr]").prop('disabled', true);
        $("[id$=ddlFPgto]").prop('disabled', true);
        $("[id$=btnImage2]").attr("src", data.CliImagemS);
        $("[id$=txtApelido]").val($.trim(data.CliApelido));

    } else {
        $("[id$=txtCodigo]").val("");
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCapture");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };

    $("[id$=imgCapture]").attr("src", '');
    if (data.CliFoto) {
        $("[id$=hdfPerfil]").val(data.CliFoto);
        image.src = data.CliFoto;
    }
    else {
        $("[id$=hdfPerfil]").val('');
    }
    if (data.CliFotoRG) {
        $("[id$=hdfrg]").val(data.CliFotoRG);
    } else {
        $("[id$=hdfrg]").val('');
    }
    if (data.CliFotoCPF) {
        $("[id$=hdfcpf]").val(data.CliFotoCPF);
    } else {
        $("[id$=hdfcpf]").val('');
    }
    if (data.CliFotoFicha) {
        $("[id$=hdfFicha]").val(data.CliFotoFicha);
    } else {
        $("[id$=hdfFicha]").val('');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o erro causa a saída do método, o que pode ser feito é dividir o método que está muito extenso em vários métodos, e colocar tratamento de erro (**try catch**) nos métodos. Segue exemplo de tratamento de erro. 
[W3 - JS - Try Catch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)